# How to pass the destination path to downloadTaskWithURL()

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have two types of media files that I want to download with `downloadTaskWithURL`: Video and Images. However, it's all good and dandy to store those files under the `Document` directory in the users' home directory but I want to store these files based on wether they are video or image under the subdirectories `Documents/video` and `Documents/images` respectively. I am thinking of two approaches:

- Download the file, figure out the MIME for it and store it in the right directory
- Pass the destination directory (`Documents/images` or `Documents/video`) to `downloadTaskWithURL` and save it accordingly upon the call to `didFinishDownloadingToURL`

I couldn't find a way to pass the destination directory to `downloadTaskWithURL` is there a way to that?

Answer (score 0):

You will get a temporary destination path in the delegate call:

```
URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:
```

From there, copy the resource to a permanent destination.

[NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate/URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:)

Comment: I am trying to find out if there's a way to pass the permanent destination, in advance, through `downloadTaskWithURL`

Comment: What is the problem with moving the file? It's not like you need to copy anything?

Comment: I want to move the files, based on whether they are video or image files, into `Documents/video` or `Documents/audio` respectively.

Comment: You can separate tasks with "downloadTask.taskIdentifier" property, assuming you know their type in advance.